# transform scale button on hover (bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to scale up the button when hovered. I tried to change the color to see if i target it correctly and that worked. 
But the transform doesnt. I'm using bootstrap

```
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    border-radius: 2.25rem;
}

.btn-primary {

    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #EB71A4;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #EB71A4, #EB4481);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EB71A4, #EB4481);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #EB71A4, #EB4481);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #EB71A4, #EB4481);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #EB71A4, #EB4481);
}

.btn:hover {
    display: inline-block;
    color: green !important;
    transform: scale(2.5) !important;
}


<a href="#kontakt" class="btn btn-primary animate-pop-in shadow">Termin vereinbaren</a>
```

Comment: @Marburc it seems to work. What are you looking exactly? Do you want to add transition effect to the scale property?

Comment: I mean scale indeed. I just tried it on codepen and it worked fine. But the same code in my codeeditor doesn't work. :(